# What do Empire / First order officers wear in front of chest?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars, Imperial officers and first order officers wear some kind of mini tubes in front of chests, what are they?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I was so tempted to write an answer, but after going through Wikia, I came up with the term for these. Then I further googled it and found that it has been already asked and answered. So, I am voting to close it as duplicate.